# Unset all POST data - PHP

Tags: php, post, unset

Will `unset($_POST)` remove all POST variables in PHP?

Or do you have to go one by one using `unset($_POST['varname'])` ?

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: intuitively I think unset($_POST) would work as its just an array. Never tested this myself. But like @MikeVelazco asked, why/what is this for?

Comment: @TCooper - I never tried it either as it turns out, in 7 years of PHP programing... lol

Comment: This is a bad code smell. There shouldn't be any reason to do this. If you feel you must do this then you have a significant design flaw somewhere in your application and a ton of technical debt on your plate.

Comment: I just can't imagine the use of this If SO had support for gifs, I'd definetively put one [here](https://gph.is/2gj3Im3),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try setting it instead:

```
$_POST = [];
```

That said, IMO it's generally a bad practice to directly modify PHP's Super Global arrays, but whatever.

Unsetting might work, I assume you tried it as it's trivial to do.  I myself have never tried unsetting it, so who knows it might just work....

Comment: I don't think there's anything particularly wrong with modifying these variables. I have a script that unsets each `$_GET[]` element after it validates it, then at the end it checks whether `$_GET` is empty to see if there were any unexpected params.

Comment: To me it feels wrong because you are losing data in your application, it sort of increases entropy in my mind, because you can never get that data back.  But I did add IMO, as that is just my Opinion.   Thanks!